# How can I launch php script from console

Tags: php, linux, console

How can I launch a php script from Linux console?

For example, I have myscript.php file. I should be able to launch it like `myscript` from console (I can create and use any other scripts)

Also, I should be able to send parameters to it like `myscript dosome [-n <count>]`. Can I do this?

Comment: You can do `php myscript.php arg1=arg1 arg2=arg2`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That's the easiest part, but I must run it like `myscript somearg -n 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run php script from shell with argumets you must create bash script, name it  `myscript` and add this code (change `php` to your php installation dir)

```
"php" myscript.php $*
```

And add script folder to Linux PATH

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/
```

Then you can access the script with `myscript arg1 -n 20`. You can access arguments via `$argv` variable in php script

Answer (score 0):

You could find it with very simple Google search.

So you should install PHP-CLI first. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

After that you should write some code to your php file:

```
nano example.php
```

and write

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

For run this script you should give permission:

```
sudo chmod 755 example.php
```

And can run it as:

```
./example.php
```

Comment: Yea, that how I did this. But the task is to run it like `example`, and not `./example.php`

Comment: if you want to start with name, you should put it to `/bin` folder. and add to your first line of your file `#!/bin/php5-cli` or whereever you installed the php-cli.